# Error happens only when debugging class in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I am traying to code an AVL Tree class in c++ that supports the normal operations for homework.
while trying code the `insert` member function I found out that when I debug and put a break point in this member function the debugger goes crazy.
to make sure it is not something that I code wrong I changed the code to this simple one to see what happens:

```
template<class X,class Y>
void AvlTree<X,Y>::insert(const X& key,const Y& data)
{
    if(this==nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"I am null"<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"insorted"<<std::endl;
}
```

It turns out that while running the program:

```
int main()
{
   AvlTree<int,int> tree;
   tree.insert(1,1);
}
```

the `insert` function prints "insorted" but while debugging the program and putting a break point on the `<<"insorted"<<` it prints "I am null" a lot of times. I don't really get why the `this` pointer is null while calling it on a non null tree.
is someone knows what seems to be the problem?

Comment: If this==nullptr you might have a serious problem.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. Without the rest of the class implementation, it's difficult to understand what is happening. The only way a this pointer can be null is through [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336294/in-which-case-the-c-this-pointer-can-be-null).

Comment: `this==nullptr` means your program has done something highly illegal. You need to stop and find out what it was. Use a debugger.