# Assignment-operator and null pointer in C++

Tags: c++

given the following C++ code:

```
class XY
{
public:
    int p;
    XY(int i):p{i}
    {}

    
    XY& operator=(const XY& cs)
    {
        if (==nullptr) //????
        {
            p=0;
            return *this;
        }
        
        ...
        return *this;
    }

};


int main ()
{
    XY a=3;
    XY *s=nullptr;
    a=*s;
}
```

a is type of XY and s is a pointer of this class that points to null.
How can I program the assignment-operator so that if s is a null pointer, that a.p=0?

Comment: You can't. You don't have any influce on the dereferencing `*s`. You *could* overload the assignment operator to take a pointer, which I would not recommend.

Comment: `cs` is not a `nullptr`. References can't be null.

Comment: How about `XY& operator=(XY const*)`? But not something I recommend. And you need to assign using the *pointer*, not dereference it.

Comment: With that said, this feels very much as a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need to use pointers? Why do you need to detect null pointers? What is the actual and underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You could overload the operator to take a `nullptr_t`, but yeah, why?

Comment: Why are you attached to writing `a = *s` when `s` is a null pointer?  What does `*s` even mean when `s` is a null pointer?  What do you hope/think will be passed as an argument to the assignment operator as the `const XY& cs` argument after being given `*s` when `s` is a nullptr?  You may _think_ this means something in C++ but the behaviour is not defined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is definitely an XY problem.  The class is even called `XY`! ;)

Comment: When there's a bug in a program that results in a null pointer and that causes a crash, the correct fix is not to avoid or work around the crash, but to figure out the bug that resulted in a null pointer.

Comment: Either a reference is valid, or a reference is **undefined behavior**.  A reference cannot ever validly be **null**.  Hence, there is no need to check to ensure a reference is not a `nullptr`.  (That's C++.  In some other languages, references can be null.  Those languages have *different semantics* for what constitutes a "reference".)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `XY *s = nullptr;` does not perform assignment, it performs copy-initialization. In that scenario, `operator=` is not called. `a = *s;` dereferences the null pointer and binds a reference to the result, which is undefined behavior.

In your code ...

> ```cpp
> XY& operator=(const XY& cs)
> {
>     if (==nullptr) //????
> ```

... the null pointer check is unnecessary. References cannot be null in C++, only pointers can be.

While it is undefined behavior, you might be able to diagnose this undefined behavior by checking

```cpp
if (&cs == nullptr)
```

However, since a compiler knows that references cannot refer to a "null object", there is no guarantee that this check won't be optimized away by the compiler.

#### See Also

- [Is null reference possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364536/5740428)
- [Why don't I need to check if references are invalid/null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524870/5740428)
- [In which cases is the "this" pointer null in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31336294/5740428)