# Using placement new on nullptr in decltype() or operator noexcept() context

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, decltype, noexcept

Is it allowed by the Standard to write `decltype(::new (nullptr) T(std::declval< Args >()...))` or `noexcept(::new (nullptr) T(std::declval< Args >()...))`? Particularly interested placement `new` on `nullptr` correctness. Considering following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct S { S(int) { ; } ~S() = delete; };

struct A
{
    template< typename T,
              bool is_noexcept = noexcept(::new (nullptr) S(std::declval< T >())) >
    A(T && x) noexcept(is_noexcept)
        : s(new S(std::forward< T >(x)))
    { ; }

    S * s;
};

static_assert(std::is_constructible< A, int >{});
static_assert(!std::is_constructible< A, void * >{});
```

Disabler `typename = decltype(S(std::declval< T >()))` would need presence of destructor, but placement `new` not.

Nevertheless unevaluated context of `decltype` and operator `noexcept` I wondering about conformance to the Standard. Because compiler may prove 100% incorectness of the tested expression.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::is_nothrow_constructible`?

Comment: @KerrekSB No. `std::is_nothrow_constructible` is incorrect for me.

Comment: @KerrekSB [Recently discussed.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909390/non-trivial-destructor-make-class-non-trivially-constructible)

Comment: Why not use `new(std::nothrow)`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: Or why not `::new (std::declval<void*>())` ?

Comment: All proposals are interesting. `nullptr` is quite short and it does not require anything from `std::`.

Comment: But I guess one could supply a custom placement-allocation function for `nullptr` / `nullptr_t`...

Comment: Can I use it in mentioned context?

Comment: @dyp Placement `new` can't be overloaded/replaced, as I know.

Comment: Allocation functions can be overloaded: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f8175408ef1dd0f

Comment: _" it does not require anything from `std::`"_ So what? That's a poor criteria. You already have to `#include <new>` so trying to avoid `std::nothrow` is just silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all published versions of the standard it is OK to pass a null pointer to placement new, and the compiler is required to handle that case, so the code is OK if it calls `::operator new(size_t, void*)` with a null pointer.

However, a class could have overloaded `operator new(size_t, nullptr_t)` in which case your expression would use that, and so you can't know exactly what would happen (e.g. it might be deleted, or it might be `noexcept(false)`).

In the working draft for C++17 it is undefined behaviour if a reserved placement allocation function returns null (this was changed following discussion arising from [a question I asked here and on the committee lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571103/passing-null-pointer-to-placement-new)). It's not clear whether that means that it is actually called and returns null, or whether even your usage would be undefined.

I would prefer not to risk it, and would use something that more clearly expresses the intention. Since what you are trying to do is test whether construction (but not destruction) can throw, by using a `new` expression that won't throw, say exactly that, and use `new(std::nothrow)`, or use an expression that uses a `void*` that is not provably a null pointer: `new (std::declval<void*>())`.

This avoids any confusion due to using `nullptr` when the property you are testing is unrelated to `nullptr`. Involving `nullptr` just complicates things, by making the reader wonder if the use of `nullptr` is significant, or if you're just being lazy and using that as a shorthand for "some `void*` pointer value".